# monaco-editor/react text drop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, monaco-editor

I am using monaco-editor/react in my next.js application, the editor works fine.
when I drag some text from outside the editro and drop it inside the editor, the text doesn't get inserted.

here is my code, did I make any mistake?

```
import Editor from '@monaco-editor/react';

export default function MyEditor(props){
    return (
        <Editor
          height="90vh"
          defaultLanguage="javascript"
          defaultValue="//some comment"
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any support for external text drag&drop in monaco editor (see [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1050#issuecomment-419060169)).